# Make Zuul the unique entry point of my application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, netflix-zuul

My application contains a service named "service" on port 8081 with some APIs like

- localhost:8081/api/services
- localhost:8081/api/services/id
- ...

With Zuul which run on port 8761, I can now access to these APIs like that

- localhost:8761/service/api/services
- localhost:8761/service/api/services/id

However, it is still possible to use the previous APIs (directly to the service). How is it possible to block them, in order to make Zuul the unique entry point ?

Comment: You should not block them, but reroute them internally to the new service. Why do want to break all usages of the existing services? That is like the exact opposite of good practice.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045466/spring-boot-force-all-traffic-to-come-through-gateway-service

Comment: you could use docker, put all the services inside the same network and don't expose the ports on `service` container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a service bound to localhost it is only accessible from that box.  You don't need to do any more than that.